# Hadoop map reduce removing values less than or more than in mapper

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    fulldate = words[1]
    year = fulldate[0:4]
    print '%s\t%s' % (year, words[15])
```

The values that are being mapped in words[15] are temperature values from a txt file that come from column 16 (or 15 for computer count. 0-15). 
ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/uscrn/products/daily01/2010/CRND0103-2010-AK_St._Paul_4_NE.txt

As you can see the first 10-20 results show -9999. The rest are numbers between 0 and 100.

I want to filter out these -9999 values before sending to the reducer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple to skip the ones you don't want. If the value is not in the range you want, just don't print it, eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    fulldate = words[1]
    year = fulldate[0:4]
    if words[15] >= 0 && words[15] <= 100
        print '%s\t%s' % (year, words[15])
```

It is fine to not produce an output for each input record, or even produce multiple output records for each input (by doing multiple prints) if the application requires it.